# WCF COM Interop With Complex Types

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, com-interop

I want to create a WCF service with COM Interop with which I need to pass complex data. Preferrably an array of custom class objects. I am not sure how to achieve this and there is a lack of decent examples.

I only found one similar question on Stackoverflow here

[Calling C# From Unmanaged C++ Passing Or Returning "Complex" Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394090/calling-c-sharp-from-unmanaged-c-passing-or-returning-complex-types)

However, the solution was to just use a C++/CLI dll instead but this is not an option for me. The C++ application that will call it statically links the C++ runtime and I have been told that this mustn't be changed.

Comment: Maybe this can be usefull: http://codereply.com/answer/3qkhjy/create-wcf-service-unmanaged-c-clients.html

Comment: So to clarify, you want to call a WCF service from a com application? Why do you need com interop for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create a WCF service with COM Interop

OK, but what direction do you want the call to go? For COM -> .Net you need to create a [COM Callable Wrapper](http://I%20want%20to%20create%20a%20WCF%20service%20with%20COM%20Interop). For .Net -> COM you need to create a [Runtime Callable Wrapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe(v=vs.110).aspx).

It sounds like you are trying to call .Net from COM, but then this begs the question why are you trying to call a WCF service via interop? If you want to call the service, then consume the service endpoint and call them.

Answer (score 0):

Approach is unclear to me.
I am not pretty much sure but same problem came to me for desktop App ,
If you want to use COM components better have a wrapper(RCW) around COM where you refer to PIAs(Primary interop  Assemblies)

And then from your main Project(WCF service) refer to this wrapper project instead of directly refering to COM.